# Why do I get "InvalidOperationException: No current row" with this code?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-ce, invalidoperationexception

I'm trying to retrieve a row from a table using the *GetInventoryRecordForUPC()* method below. I can retrieve the row fine in LINQPad by entering "*SELECT invName, line_id, ref_no, upc_code, description, department, vendor_id, upc_pack_size, pack_size, id, unit_cost, unit_list, unit_qty, new_item FROM Inventory WHERE upc_code = '76145513'*" (the value passed in "upc" is "76145513") in my test scenario.

But when the method below runs, the app crashes, and the log file contains:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No current row
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.CheckValidRow()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.VerifyType(Int32 i, DbType typ)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
   at HHS.TestHHSDBUtils.GetInventoryRecordForUPC(String upc)
```

The method has the table's create statement commented out to show the names and data types of the columns.

```
public Inventory GetInventoryRecordForUPC(String upc)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
TestHHSDBUtils.GetInventoryRecordForUPC");
    Inventory inv = new Inventory();
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new 
SQLiteConnection(HHSUtils.GetDBConnection()))
    {
        conn.Open();
        const string qry = "SELECT invName, line_id, ref_no, upc_code, 
description, department, vendor_id, upc_pack_size, pack_size, id, unit_cost, 
unit_list, unit_qty, new_item FROM Inventory WHERE upc_code = @UPCCode";
        //CREATE TABLE Inventory(invName TEXT, line_id INTEGER, ref_no 
TEXT, upc_code TEXT, description TEXT, department REAL, vendor_id TEXT, 
upc_pack_size INTEGER, pack_size INTEGER, id TEXT, unit_cost REAL, unit_list 
REAL, unit_qty REAL, new_item INTEGER, siteNum TEXT, Created TEXT, Modified 
TEXT)";

        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("UPCCode", upc));
            using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                inv.invName = rdr.GetString(0);
                inv.line_id = rdr.GetInt32(1);
                inv.ref_no = rdr.GetString(2);
                inv.upc_code = rdr.GetString(3);
                inv.description = rdr.GetString(4);
                inv.department = rdr.GetFloat(5);
                inv.vendor_id = rdr.GetString(6);
                inv.upc_pack_size = rdr.GetInt32(7);
                inv.pack_size = rdr.GetInt32(8);
                inv.id = rdr.GetString(9);
                inv.unit_cost = rdr.GetFloat(10);
                inv.unit_list = rdr.GetFloat(11);
                inv.unit_qty = rdr.GetFloat(12);
                inv.new_item = rdr.GetInt32(13);
            }
        }
        return inv;
    }
}
```

The Inventory class is declared this way:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public String invName { get; set; }
    public int line_id { get; set; }
    public String ref_no { get; set; }
    public String upc_code { get; set; }
    public String description { get; set; }
    public double department { get; set; }
    public String vendor_id { get; set; }
    public int upc_pack_size { get; set; }
    public int pack_size { get; set; }
    public String id { get; set; } // id, here?
    public double unit_cost { get; set; } // REAL in SQLite
    public double unit_list { get; set; } // REAL in SQLite
    public double unit_qty { get; set; }  // REAL in SQLite
    public int new_item { get; set; }
    // Create Table code adds TEXT siteNum, Created and Modified columns
}
```

Why in John Steinbeck's pet poodle would this cause a "*InvalidOperationException: No current row*"?!?

Comment: Don't you have to call `rdr.Read()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try calling `rdr.Read()`:

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("UPCCode", upc));
    using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            // Set inv properties
            break; // (if you only want the first item returned)
        }
    }
}

return inv;
```

Comment: There should only be one record, but I'll add the break just in case (no pun intended). Is "break" the only keyword named after a dance?

Comment: If it's zero or one then just replace the 'while' by 'if', and no need for a 'break'

Answer (score 4):

I also got the same exception using System.Data.SQLite.Core after I upgraded to version 1.0.96.0. I used the following [nuget](https://www.nuget.org) command to revert back to 1.0.94.0

```
Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.Core -Version 1.0.94.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you download SQLIte as a NuGet package?

I am not sure what the actual reason is, but I got the same exception as you did using System.Data.SQLite.Core version 1.0.96.0.

Then I downgraded to version 1.0.94.0, and now everything works fine.
(I had the 1.0.94.0 dll laying around on my local disk)

Comment: I have no clue; I'm at a different job, and doing totally different stuff, now, and don't recall the details of this...